# Question on data transfer from local kafka to kafka google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I have been evaluating a requirement to move test data from kafka local setup to kafka in google cloud. which means integrate both.I plan to use the following approach to create a pipeline. Please let me know your thoughts if i am headed in right direction.

**I will setup kafka locally on my desktop and create a topic called TopicA. I then plan to produce messages to this kafka topic TopicA. The consumer of this TopicA would pick these messages sequentially and connect to the GCP kafka topic called TopicB and start posting message to the gcp TopicB. Finally the consumer of the GCP TopicB would consume these messages thus completing the created pipeline and validating these messages.**

To update i do not have much idea about GCP need to explore. Any ideas or pointers to any code base/docs/SO would be highly welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at Kafka MirrorMaker (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330)? Sounds like it may solve your problem, unless I misunderstood it..

Comment: @mazaneicha yes you are correct i want to connect not through shell programs like mirror maker but through java code. do you know any solutions for it

Comment: MM is a standalone tool for copying data between two Kafka clusters written in Java (not a "shell program"). Its a Kafka consumer and producer hooked together. Sure, nothing is stopping you from writing your own version of MirrorMaker, but why?